# mdInput messages show animation called on invalid messages element:

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages

Not sure why I'm getting the following message. Has anyone else encountered this in AngularJS/Angular Material? What am I doing wrong? The message itself seems a little vague.

```
mdInput messages show animation called on invalid messages element:
md-input-container.md-block.md-icon-right.md-default-theme.md-input-has-value
```

Comment: I just started getting this also, let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I fixed it by setting `form` tag name attribute the same way `ng-messages` was expecting it to be

Comment: my problem resolved by adding the name to input.

Answer (score 12):

Old question, but just in case anyone bumps into this, you need to supply an error message for the input field. The error is saying that it can't animate the error message into view because the messages element is missing.

In your `md-input-container` include the `ng-messages` element to handle the error. For example, if you have a form called `myFrm` with a required email address input named `email`, your code would be something like this:

```
<form name="myFrm">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="myFrm.email" name="email" required/>
    <div ng-messages="myFrm.email.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">Email address is required</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
  <!-- Other form elements.... -->
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @AmmarHasan, I just hide my ng-messages div keeping the internals ng-message's divs even making them useless: ex: <div ng-messages="myForm.email.$error" ng-hide="true"><div ng-message="required"></div></div>

Comment: ng-hide="true"
Not help at all.